# Can I make Store with Rest Proxy convert to Store with Memory Proxy in ExtJS4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a Store with the Rest Proxy. In my case, i want to make it from rest proxy with data convert to memory proxy with origin data, and in memory proxy mode, i will modify some record and save it which doesn't need to save to Server.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'my_rest_model',
    autoLoad: true
}
```

is there are any method can convert it to store with memory proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do that. A store doesn't need to write anything back to the server. As long as you do nothing to trigger it, by either:

- Syncing the store (manually or with the autoSync config)
- Calling save on the model directly

It won't write anything back to the server.